# Maven and Clear Case

Tags: java, maven, clearcase

I'm new to Continuous Integration and I'm looking for any briefed sum of the basic concepts of working both with Maven and Clear Case while using Eclipse environment for developing in Java.

All the information I've found so far is too generic, as given in these companies' sites, or too specific, i.e. how to make a specific operation in a specific mode.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't much information beside [SCM Implementation: ClearCase](http://maven.apache.org/scm/clearcase.html) (in the Maven site), used with a [ClearCase plugin in Eclipse](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21432752), as mentioned in [this thread](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=425996).

Considering that each time a '`checkout`' of code is performed, the ClearCase SCM provider creates a new snapshot view using the `cleartool mkview` command, that means it is for a full ClearCase installation only, not CCRC (the Remote Client).